# How to Customise SharePoint List Alert Emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, modern-experience, power-automate

I just found a, potentially, very useful feature of SharePoint Lists and Power Automate but I need some help to make the most of it.

Under the Automate drop-down in the modern experience list, there is an option to create 'Rules' instructing the list to perform certain actions when particular conditions are satisfied.

For Example: When [Date Column] = Todays Date, send email to [User Column].

This appears to work well and has the potential to save me a lot of work with Power Automate workflows if I can find the answer to one question: ***How can I customize the text of the email that is sent?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to customize the email template while using list rules in SharePoint online.

Check more information about rules in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists at: [Rules in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/27/rules-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)